# Autocompletion using Java not JavaScript

Tags: java, search-engine

I have to make what is called "Hypertext Searching" in my application. Basically, you start typing in a field, and just like Google for each letter you type in, the relevant search matches changes. The only difference is, that I will fill a table with information, and every time the user types a letter in the box, the table will change content based on what you start typing.

An example would be that if you wanted to look for a *Harry Potter* book, you start typing Harry.

For each letter you type, the table changes, nailing down letter for letter what book it is you are looking for.

My question is: Which way would be the best or most appropriate way of doing it efficiently? I am going to have an array list with objects in, that I can access and show on the table.

Comment: Are you restricted to certain technologies? Are you allowed to use libraries (and to what extent)?

Comment: I am allowed to use Libraries yes.

Comment: Hi Vipar: Do you need something like Auto Recommendation (like in combobox at Google) or are you looking out for a Google Instant like feature where the search results page keep changing results based on your inputs in textbox?

Comment: The Latter please :)
If you have any suggestions that is.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is called autocompletion.

There is plenty of solution if you search on google "javascript autocompletion".

Personnally I use jquery ui which has a component for that http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

EDIT: My bad, the question is about java, not javascript

Comment: This is not JavaScript. This is Java.

Comment: Wooops! Sorry. So what the technology? Swing? you can also search on google swing autocomplete... There's a lot of solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried
[SuggestBox using GWT](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/gwt/suggestion-box.shtml) and
[Facebook Style Autocomplete](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/creating_a_facebook_style_autocomplete)?